# Challenges with auxiliary routers in Angular 7

Tags: javascript, angular

Part of my Angular app requires two components to be shown at the same time, other parts of my app only require a single component to be shown.  I'm having no issues with routing related to the 'pages' that only have single components on them, but I am having some challenges with the one where I'm taking advantage of the auxiliary router.  Code with comments is included below.  Basically getting a route not found error when I'm trying to get 'back' from the view that uses the aux router.

```js
//Relevant import to support routing in app.module
import {
  Routes,
  RouterModule
} from '@angular/router';

//Route array in app.module
const appRoutes: Routes = [{
    path: '',
    component: HomeComponent
  },
  {
    path: 'admin',
    component: BuilderComponent
  },
  {
    path: 'sandbox',
    component: SandboxComponent
  },
  {
    path: 'adventure',
    component: GuideComponent
  },
  {
    path: 'scanner',
    component: ScannerComponent,
    outlet: 'secondary'
  }
];

//relvant import in imports array in app.module
RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes)

  //Content of my app.component.html file
  <
  div class = "container" >
  <
  app - header > < /app-header> <
router - outlet > < /router-outlet> <
router - outlet name = "secondary" > < /router-outlet> < /
  div >

  //Code in one of my components HTML file that is attached to a button and successfully calls the page with two components
  [routerLink] = "[ {
outlets: {
primary: 'adventure',
secondary: 'scanner'
}
}
]
"

//Code I'm trying to use in the 'multi component' view that tries to get back to the 'home' page
[routerLink] = "[ {
outlets: {
primary: '',
secondary: 'sandbox' //This is a blank HTML component so that it doesn't screw up the look of components that don't need the aux router. Super hacky and am welcome to suggestions on how to fix this as well.
}
}
]
"
```